# How to add character to a string element in a tuple or list?

Tags: python, string, replace

I have the following sentence:

```
sentence = "<s> online auto body <s>"
```

And I would like first to make words 3-grams out of it as:

```
('<s>', 'outline', 'auto')
('online', 'auto', 'body')
('auto', 'body', '<s>')
```

To do so I used the following code:

```
sentence = '<s> online auto body <s>'
n = 3
word_3grams = ngrams(sentence.split(), n)
for grams in word_3grams: 
    print(grams)
```

Now, I would like to get "#" at the beginning and at the end of every word, as follows:

```
('#<s>#','#outline#','#auto#')
('#online#', '#auto#', '#body#')
('#auto#', '#body#', '#<s>#')
```

But I don't know what to do in order to get it. As a side note elements here are tuples but it wouldn't mind using lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution from the beginning:

```
sentence = "<s> online auto body <s>" 
n = 3

# Split the sentence into words and append the '#' symbol.
words = tuple(map(lambda w: '#'+w+'#', sentence.split()))

# Create a list of elements consisting of three consecutive words.
splits = [words[i:i+n] for i in range(len(words)-(n-1))]

#Print results.
for elem in splits:
    print(elem)
```

Output:

```
('#<s>#', '#online#', '#auto#')
('#online#', '#auto#', '#body#')
('#auto#', '#body#', '#<s>#')
```

Answer (score 1):

You want a sliding window like feature.

```
from itertools import islice

sentence = "<s> online auto body <s>"
myList = sentence.split()
myList = ['#' + word + '#' for word in myList]

slidingWindow = [islice(myList, s, None) for s in range(3)]
print(list(zip(*slidingWindow)))

# [('#<s>#', '#online#', '#auto#'), ('#online#', '#auto#', '#body#'), ('#auto#', '#body#', '#<s>#')]
```

Comment: because of `'#' + word + '#'`

Comment: `print(zip(*slidingWindow))` only works in python 2. you need to force iteration in python 3

Comment: I tried it with the code above with Python 3.5 and all I get is `<itertools.islice object at 0x000001A6E69D3DB8>`. How could I force iteration?

Comment: Corrected, you can try again @Marisa

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the strings, try:

```
map(lambda s: "#" + s + "#", sentence.split())
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python a tuple is immutable, which means it can't be modified.
As you somehow suggested, it would be better to use lists, more precisely
 [list comprehension](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-list-comprehensions-in-python-3):

```
aList = ['auto', 'body', '<s>']
newList = ['#' + item + '#' for item in aList]
print (newList)
# ['#auto#', '#body#', '#<s>#']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using list comprehension and [format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) function:

```
word_3grams = [('<s>', 'outline', 'auto'),
               ('online', 'auto', 'body'),
               ('auto', 'body', '<s>')]

for grams in word_3grams: 
    print ["{pad}{data}{pad}".format(pad='#', data=s) for s in grams]

['#<s>#', '#outline#', '#auto#']
['#online#', '#auto#', '#body#']
['#auto#', '#body#', '#<s>#']
```